# Adjectival order with adjectival phrase

Tags: english-to-german, adjective, word-order

I am trying to say:

> the increased economic value provided by the student.

Is this the correct ordering of the adjectives?

> der vom Studenten angebotene erhöhte wirtschaftliche Wert

Comment: The order is practically correct, but you chose a wrong word for practically everything except for *Studenten* and *Wert.*

Comment: @Jan How would you word it?

Comment: ‘Der durch den Studenten verursachte erhöhte ökonomische Wert.’

Comment: We need more context. I think *erbringen* is better than *verursachen*. Persons *verursachen* negative effects but I think the effect described is positive. *Beitragen* is also an alternative.

Comment: @Janka Yeah, that was basically just the first wording I came up with that didn’t sound terrible. By no means perfect ;)

Comment: The english verb »to provide« can be translated into German in 123 different ways: http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=provide (click on "weitere Verben anzeigen" to see more than the first 15 translations). We need more context to know which possibility is the right one.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast For one the question isn't about finding the right translation for "provided", for another there are not that many meaningful translations for "provided" anyway, and there's already enough context given for a good translation.

Comment: What is the question? The word order of 'erhöht' and 'wirtschaftlich'?

Comment: The word order of 'erhört' and 'wirtschaftlich' in relation to 'vom Studenten angeboten': do the simple adjectives precede or follow the adjectival phrase, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @charlie harding, then please update your question ("edit" button)

Comment: *...der erhöhte Wirtschaftsbeitrag des Studenten...*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order of the adjectives is correct.

"Wirtschaftliche" has to stand right besides "Wert" because it references it directly. It would sound kind of strange to put it the other way around.
(Ignoring the fact, that the sentence sounds pretty strange anyway because of the choice of words)

I'd rather go with a relative clause

> Der erhöhte wirtschaftliche Wert, der vom Studenten angegeben/bereitgestellt/[whatever fits the context best] wurde